# How to print content of a label in java?

Tags: java, swing, printing, label

I have created a label and added an image to it using the seticon property.
Now I want to print that image but I am unable to do so.

I tried with .print(Graphics g) method but I dont know what is that graphics??

If someone can help me in printing the label, I would be really grateful to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implenent Printable interface
see for example [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.print/simplest-print-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to print anything explicitly  just try following

```
 ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon("PATH_TO_IMAGE_FILE");  

 //Create a label with your image file  
 JLabel label=new JLabel(ii);  

 //Create a window using JFrame with title ( Put image on JLabel )  
 JFrame frame=new JFrame("Put image on JLabel");  

 //Add created label into JFrame  
 frame.add(label);
```

**Update as per your clarification :**

Follow [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Printanimageout.htm) , and pass `label.getGraphics()` to `printAll()` method

Comment: I think u didnt got it...
I am referring printing as taking a hard copy here :))