# Print text and image on the paper in java

Tags: java, swing

I an new in Java. I need to print exactly the screen of the JPanel which has the label has image. Would someone provide the link or guideline for me to study. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22244116#22244116) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241711/setting-print-size-of-a-jlabel-and-put-a-jradiobutton-on-the-print/22242658#22242658)

Comment: Do you mean you want to display a Window on the screen with a JPanel and a JLabel or do you mean you want to print a `JPanel` with a `JLabel` in it to a printer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I want to print it to a printer. Thanks for your example to guide me to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one or just use google with "java swing tutorial" or "java awt tutorial":
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/firstprograms/

Comment: 1- It has nothing to do with printing the components to a printer and 2- Uses `null` layout which makes an incredibly bad example

Comment: 1 - I'am pretty sure, that he was thinking just about displaying (printing) this on screen. 2 - I fully agree with this, it was first link from google. I think that that for creating JButton on on JPanel is good almost every tutorial, at least at the very beginning

Comment: I'll take the first point as been a difference between how we read it then.

Comment: No agree, it's unclear, my first point is mute till proven otherwise ;)

Comment: Ok, he admitted, that was thinking about using a printer, I agree with you:)