# Jframe save into pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans, itext

I want to sava a JFrame form  into a PDF file. How can i do it?

For example my JFame form that is Invoice receipt consists of Jlabel JTextfield and Jbutton and i want to save it into pdf file how to make it by clicking a button?

Do I need to use "Itext"? Sorry, i am java beginner.Please help. Thanks in advanced.

All i can see is [How to print content of a label in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942480/how-to-print-content-of-a-label-in-java)

Please refer to my Jframe [JFrame Invoice save into pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxwE1.png)

Comment: You could capture a PNG image using this example: [Obtain image of JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/swing-obtain-image-of-jframe) then write that image to a PDF.

Comment: Is there any other way instead of capture a image ?

Comment: did you check something around graphics?

Comment: sorry @ChannaJayamuni i dont get what u mean..

Comment: @JavaNew Is the PDF blank or new? Does the PDF already exist with blank fields, and you're trying to translate the existing data from the JComponent fields into the PDF? I'm having a hard time understanding what the finished result should look like.

Comment: what I want to do is

1) I will create a new template pdf and import into netbeans. I will just need to add the existing data from the JFrame form to the template.

2) I just save the JFrame form into PDF. Thats mean whatever i see in the Invoice JFrame form i want to save it into pdf file.

Any one of the method above will do.